# Data Scrub off Interactive Map - Cal Fire related

Tags: web, interactive, esri, data-scrubbing

http://calfire-forestry.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=5306cc8cf38c4252830a38d467d33728&extent=-13547810.5486%2C4824920.1673%2C-13518764.4778%2C4841526.1117%2C102100

how can i scrub the locations off this? Don't need addresses, just want a count of (ideally) red vs black boxes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

right click, use inspect to see everything that loads. figured it out